# Struggling between Job and JobConf while using TableMapReduceUtil and MultipleOutputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to Read HBase table TableMapReduceUtil and dump data into HDFS (Don't ask me why. It is weired but don't have any other option). So, to achieve that, I want to manipulate final file names (emitted by reducer) w.r.t the reducer key.

On the mapper side I was able to dump hbase rotryingws to HDFS in default order. But to override reducer outputfile format (name as per key), I figured out that **MultipleOutputFormat** class for reducer (which is absent on 0.20 due to some interface mess up, read somewhere) and the old one takes only JobConf. But if I try to write the code with old **JobConf**, I am not able to Use HBase 0.90's **TableMapReduceUtil** which only takes **Job** class

Doesn't have much handson with Hadoop/HBase. Had spent some time modifying existing MRJObs. 
It seems I am stuck with my approach.

Versions Hadoop-Core-0.20.;HBase 0.90.1

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to Use HBase 0.90's TableMapReduceUtil which only takes Job class.

There are [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableMapReduceUtil](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/tags/0.90.1/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapred/TableMapReduceUtil.java) and [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/tags/0.90.1/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.java) classes. The first will take JobConf (old MR API) and the second will take Job (new MR API). Use the appropriate TableMapReduceUtil class.